# Top aligning two spans with different font-size

Tags: html, css

I do have the following code:

```
<div>
  <span class='foo' style='font-size: 10px'>Foo</span>
  <span class='blah' style='font-size: 25px'>Blah</span>
</div>
```

I would like to top align both of them. At the minute, Foo is not top aligned because the font-size of Blah is bigger. How can I fix this ?

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Scipionh/pen/GJxgbQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using

```
span {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXqgKW)

As you can see using the green background both divs are aligned using their top corner. If you want to do further aligning you can although add `display: inline-block`, to stylize them and add paddings:

```
span {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.foo {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

[**DEMO #2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpebVz)

This time they look like their top is aligned (even if the first one is actually below the second one).